# Isometry identity map proof

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-analysis

Let $f : C → C$ be an isometry with equation $f(z) = e^{iθ} \bar z + b$ where $θ ∈ R$ and $b ∈ C.$ Prove that $f^2 = Id_C$ then $e^{iθ}\bar b + b = 0$.

My Attempt: Given that this is an identity map, $f^2(0) = 0,f^2 (1)=1, ,f^2 (i) = i $ So then $f^2(0) = (e^{iθ} (\bar 0) + b)^2 = 0$. From this $b = 0$. Then $f^2(b)=(e^{iθ}\bar b + b)^2 =(e^{iθ} (\bar 0) + 0)^2 = 0 $. This implies that $e^{iθ} (\bar b) + b = 0$ So then the proposition is true.

I don't think I did this correctly and I don't know how to begin solving this.

Comment: The assumption $f^2={\rm id}_{\mathbb C}$ indicates that by $f^2$ the composition of $f$ with itself is meant, and the assumption amounts to $f\bigl(f(z)\bigr)=z$ for all $z\in{\mathbb C}$.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter so then $f(f(z)) = z = f(e^{i \theta} \bar z +b)$?

Comment: Yes. But you have to be careful when plugging in.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter So would it then be $e^{i \theta} {(e^{i \theta} \bar z +b)} + b$ = z? bar over the parenthesis.